# How to make Firewall rules for Passive FTP which uses dynamic port?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, ftp

The following two rules allow for passive transfers which i added as Firewall rules for my FTP server.

```
//The following two rules allow the inbound FTP connection
iptables -A INPUT -s $hostIP -p tcp --dport 21 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $hostIP -p tcp --sport 21 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

// The following two rules allow for passive transfers
iptables -A INPUT -s $hostIP -p tcp --dport 1024:65535 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $hostIP  -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

My FTP was server configured by assigning passive port to range "1024:65535" and above rules worked. But now FTP server configured to bind any free port instead fix port range. So what changes required in above two rules?

**Edit**
After applying three rules for passive FTP connection mentioned in answer i have rules in following order and now it's stopped working means client is connected but unable to retrieve remote directory.

```
//The following two rules allow the inbound FTP connection
iptables -A INPUT -s $hostIP -p tcp --dport 21 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $hostIP -p tcp --sport 21 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables  -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp -s $hostIP --dport 21 -j CT --helper ftp
iptables  -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -m helper --helper ftp -s $hostIP -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables  -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -m helper --helper ftp -d $hostIP -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

Working Rules

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp -s $hostIP --dport 21 -j CT --helper ftp
iptables -A INPUT  -i eth0 -p tcp -s $hostIP -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m helper --helper ftp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -d $hostIP -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -m helper --helper ftp -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I guess you should drop `--dport 1024:65535` and `--sport 1024:65535`, but the range `1024:65535` is already unlimited. Anyway, it is a bad idea to open for an unlimited range, if your FTP server is on internet. I would recommend to make some estimate, how many clients you expect simultaneously, and allow a range of ports around your estimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `$hostIP` in your rules means a host you wish to allow FTP access for, otherwise your existing rules won't make sense to me.

If you are using unencrypted FTP, you should replace your wide-open FTP data connection rules with connection tracking.

First, add a rule that attaches a FTP connection tracking helper to any incoming FTP *command* connections:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp -s $hostIP --dport $ftpCMDport -d $ftpServerIP -j CT --helper ftp
```

Here, `$ftpCMDport` is the port in which your local FTP server accepts logins; usually it's port 21.

(Historical note: this used to happen automatically for TCP port 21, but it turned out the automatic assignment could be abused, so the automatic assignment of connection tracking helpers was made optional in Linux kernel 3.5, and later the automatic assignment feature was completely removed.)

Once the FTP command connections are being monitored by the CT helper, the firewall will "know" which ports should be allowed for legitimate FTP data connections. You'll need two more rules to actually use this information to allow incoming data connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -m helper \
   --helper ftp -s $hostIP -d $ftpServerIP -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -m helper \
   --helper ftp -s $ftpServerIP -d $hostIP -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

Together, these three rules should entirely replace your existing two rules for FTP data connections. These should be good for both active and passive connections, should your FTP server allow both types. If you only want to accept passive FTP data connections, you might want to remove the `RELATED` in the OUTPUT rule.

This was based on: https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/

---

If you are using SSL/TLS encrypted FTP, then the connection tracking helper won't be able to make sense of the encrypted FTP command traffic, and so if the FTP server will accept data connections in any free port, you cannot effectively firewall traffic by TCP ports at all, since any TCP port could become a FTP data port for some connection. Your only possibility would then be to limit traffic by IP addresses:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s $hostIP -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $hostIP  -p tcp -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Note that these are essentially your existing rules, with the `--dport` and `--sport` options removed.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have applied three rules mentioned for undecrypted FTP connection and i see my FTP client not able to Read Remote directory and it's stuck there.  Simply i am using WinSCP as client to connect FTP server but it now have issue to retrieve server directory and timeout.

Comment: The ordering of the rules is important: if you have some drop/reject rules that match the characteristics of the FTP data packets and are in the rule chain *before* the acceptance rules, the first match wins and the packets get dropped. Inability to read remote directory and timeouts sound just like a problem with data connections.

Comment: Order seems correct to me. I have updated my question after applying your solution. Please check it and possible then let me know where is issue.

Comment: If you run `iptables -L -vn`, you'll see a full listing of the iptables filtering rules, including the packet and byte counters for each rule. If the counters for rhe new data connection rules are not increasing on every data connection attempt (e.g. on every attempt to get a FTP directory listing), then some earlier rule is matching the FTP data packets and causing them to not reach the new rules. Likewise, you should check `iptables -L -vn -t raw` for the counters of the helper assignment rule.

Comment: ok, i see incoming and outcoming counter for data connection rule not increasing. I have added "iptables -L -vn" o/p in my question. Can you please verify it where is issue?

Comment: have you got chance to look my updated question?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps your kernel configuration does not include the FTP connection tracking helper feature? What does `grep CONNTRACK_FTP /boot/config-*` or `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONNTRACK_FTP` say? If it says `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP=m`, does `lsmod |grep conntrack_ftp` confirm the module is loaded? And does `iptables -L -vn -t raw` indicate the PREROUTING rule is in place?

Comment: Finally i am able to make rules working. see my updated question with working rule. One thing i did differently to make it working is added ESTABLISHED together with RELATED in INPUT rule. Without this i am not able to read remote server directory.  Do you have any comment on this?

Comment: I usually have a blanket ESTABLISHED rule at or near the beginning of my ruleset, so all connections that are allowed to begin (by other rules) will also be allowed to continue as a matter of course. Your rules are more strict in this sense, so looks like I missed that requirement. Sorry about the confusion, I'll edit my answer so as not to confuse any others.